# Best software for Mac to Windows remote control?

Tags: windows, mac, remote-access, rdp

My client has a Mac at home and wants to remote control (run apps) on a Windows XP PC at the office. What is the best software to enable this? Any Mac <-> Windows weirdness to be aware of?

Answer (score 6):

The best things will be to use the [RDP client for mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/remote-desktop/default.mspx).

Comment: Of course, you will have to enable the Remote Desktop Protocol on the windows XP PC

Comment: True Radius, but if they want to remote control the PC, they've presumably accepted they'll probably need to enable or install *something*.

Comment: This is what we use for mac users who wish to work from home, RDP to our remote desktop gateway works very well from a Mac. I'm fairly happy with how this works, and I'm speaking as someone who uses a mac at home so I'm eating my own dogfood on this one!

Comment: I'm also using the RDP client to connect from my mac at home to my pc at work ;)

Comment: Another reason to favour RDP: Cost and licence.

Comment: +1 for being right. you might edit the name to avoid confusion though "Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac" It's confusing enough that both Apple's and Microsoft's clients are called "Remote Desktop" ;-)

Answer (score 5):

RDP client for the Mac is of course the best option providing you are already have a VPN/Port forward or you are able to set it up.

Personally I would go for [Logmein](http://www.logmein.com/) (free) they have an excellent Mac Firefox plugin.  The advantage is you don't have to worry about the network side of things.  It's also SSL secured if you worry about those sorts of things!

Comment: I've just noticed that the office PC already has LogMeIn installed. I think this was done by a local vendor for remote support. Can I use this or is LogMeIn tied to the vendor (i.e. only their account can use it?)

Comment: A number of our directors have Logmein installed on their home PCs so that our support people can connect to them and sort out basic stuff when needed. Each director has their own Logmein login and account, you can connect to any of these PCs from a machine with Logmein installed. The install isn't tied to the account, you have to log into the Logmein website to authenticate as whichever account you're using.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found is [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/). It's free, open source, and it supports multiple saved sessions, shared clipboard, and a bunch of other features.

I've been using it to connect to terminal services on the server farm at work, and it works like a charm.

In fact, it's way better than the official Microsoft RDP client for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) - an oldie but a goodie.